# Trying to assigning hyperlink to pdf location inside PDF using code behind c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to assigning hyperlink to pdf location inside PDF using c# asp.net web forms.

This is my C# code assigned link url to pdf location.

```
protected void FillPDF()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> formFieldMap;

    pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../img/fullapplication_final.pdf"), ""); // need to take
    formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
    string livepath = "http://www.example.com/";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["RegistrationId"].ToString() as string))
    {
        bo.Para1 = Request.QueryString["RegistrationId"].ToString();
        bo.Para2 = "3";

        DataTable dt = bl.Admin_Get_UserInformation(bo);

        formFieldMap["text_attchedfilertpin"] = livepath + "TrainingPlan/" + dt.Rows[0]["TrainingPlan"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This code is showing an url like `www.example.com/my.pdf` as its output.

But I need the output to be like this : `click here to download pdf`

I am trying below new code to get the output as I need it:

```
HyperLink DynLink = new HyperLink();
DynLink.ID = "DynLink1";
DynLink.Text = "click here to donwload pdf";
DynLink.NavigateUrl = livepath + "TrainingPlan/" + dt.Rows[0]["TrainingPlan"].ToString();

Page.Controls.Add(DynLink);
```

But I'm not able to assign view of `pdf` using

```
formFieldMap["text_attchedfilertpin"]
```

I am looking for your help thank you in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644506/code-to-download-pdf-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: are you understand my question. @battlmonstr

Comment: Yes, just add code from the link to your hyperlink handler, and it will work.

Comment: Content-Disposition = attachment is the most important part to have.

Comment: i am not able to assing view part inside pdf formFieldMap["text_attchedfilertpin"]?. @battlmonstr

Comment: can you write your full answer. @battlmonstr

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you want now... You need a URL handler then.

Comment: in above question i have mention how i need output like : But i need output like this : click here to donwload pdf. @battlmonstr

Answer (score 0):

In order for the PDF link to be recognized as a file download, you need to add a special `Content-Disposition: attachment; file=xxx.pdf` HTTP header (see this for code example - [code to download PDF file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644506/code-to-download-pdf-file-in-c-sharp) ).

Let's say you want to have a link `http://www.example.com/plans/my123.pdf` that when clicked initiates a PDF file download of a training plan called "my123".

You can create an HTTP handler - a class `PlanPDF` that implements `IHttpHandler`. In the code of the handler you can set the right Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Length and transmit the PDF file as in the link above. [See this article for a simple example of IHttpHandler](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET)

Next you need to configure URL rewriting so that requests coming to `/plans/my123.pdf` get mapped to your handler `PlanPDF`.
This you can do in your "Web.config" (see the same codeproject article for an example).

Parse the plan name from the request URL path, and use it to determine which training plan file to transmit.

Comment: please write code as i need above will help more to me. @battlmonstr

Comment: Check this for code: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET
(`class CspxHandler`). It is almost all you need.

Comment: i need to view that link in this location formFieldMap["text_attchedfilertpin"]. @battlmonstr

Comment: please write some code text is getting confused to me, this trying since morning. @ battlmonstr

Comment: I have simplified the answer. Please read the codeproject link and ask more questions. The solution I explain should work fine with your PDF form. Please ask questions if you don't understand the solution.

Comment: see i added as answer, please write some code, will helpful. @battlmonstr

Comment: A custom HTTP handler for PDF is all you need. There's plenty of HTTP handler examples around. Here's a description of what an HTTP handler is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391130/what-is-an-httphandler-in-asp-net

Comment: till what time you are online, tomorrow i have client deadline if i face any problem i will message. @battlmonstr

Comment: Tell your client that it's Sunday and you go to church and relax. No deadlines on Sunday :)